# How to make the fastest execution of get requests in python flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have a task:

1. Get requests of 2 API endpoints **/api/1**, **/api/2** from which I get list of id's
2. For each listed *id* from point 1., get requests of **/api/x/${id}/data**

Then I use these data to fill the elements on web page. The web page is built with python flask and uwsgi.

The count of URLs I'm sending requests to is now 30 and in the future will be max 60.

My current solution is with asyncio and aiohttp but I think I'm using it wrong.

---

Here is my simplified code:

```
class MyClass:

    async def fetch_page(self, session, url):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

    async def pull_data(self):
        first_endpoint = requests.get('https://domain/api/1')
        first_endpoint = json.loads(first_endpoint.text)
        second_endpoint = requests.get('https://domain/api/2')
        second_endpoint = json.loads(second_endpoint.text)
        endpoints = {**first_endpoint, **second_endpoint}

        urls = []
        for data in endpoints:
            urls.append("https://domain/api/x/" + str(data['id']) + "/data")

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            html = await asyncio.wait([self.fetch_page(session, url) for url in urls])
        for x in html:
           # here I get the result data and send it
```

And this is how I call it:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    global loop
    my_obj = MyClass()
    loop.run_until_complete(my_obj.pull_data())
```

First point I'm thinking if later there will be more endpoints in point 1. I need to parallelise that code part too but how? should I create a new session with aiohttp or somehow join it to the existing one? 
and my page loads in 2s which is still slow, what load time is achievable in this scenario? (without getting the data the page loads always under <0.5s)

So my question is, which library/approach should I choose for this issue and how to use it correctly to speed load of my page? I will be happy with 1s load

The other approach I was thinking was to run the new process with this flask app which will get the data and cache them somewhere but I'm afraid then I don't get the "fresh" / actual data always on each page reload

Comment: your flask app will always depend on the slowest get request. You can use as much yield/await as you like, as soon as your api endpoints don't response fast enough, you can't accelereate it. How fast is a single request? Does the server scale on muitple requests? If the server on which the API (maybe single threaded flask api) is running isn't capable of serving your multiple parallel requests fast enough/or even parallel, you can't accelerate it.

Comment: Can you denormalize the data a bit such that a single request fetches more of your desired resources?

Comment: @duhaime no I can't

Comment: As a suggestion you could move to Quart (https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/index.html) its an async fork of flask and I have found it really good.

Comment: and although this article (https://hackernoon.com/threaded-asynchronous-magic-and-how-to-wield-it-bba9ed602c32) is a couple of years old it will help you understand what you need to know